# How to see who is logged on to many workstations?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, users

Before I go to work creating my own I would like to find an existing system to do the following:

- Provide a concise list of users logged on to any of the workstations
- Show workstation host name, IP, and user name
- Data should update frequently or when there is a change
- Web or console interface
- Run on a Debian/Squeeze machine
- Free/Libre software

Situation:

- 60 Ubuntu 10.04 workstations spread over 3 sites
- Sites connected by 20Mbps WAN
- one server at each site running NFS and LDAP
- Workstations configured to authenticate users via LDAP and auto mount homes  from local NFS server
- Users can log on to any machine they want

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps some [finger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_protocol) daemon already provides some of your requirements.

On my Ubuntu system there are several available:

```
$ apt-cache search finger --names-only
finger - user information lookup program
cfingerd - configurable finger daemon
efingerd - Another finger daemon for unix capable of fine-tuning your output.
finger-ldap - Finger for machines that authenticate against LDAP
fingerd - remote user information server
xfingerd - BSD-like finger daemon with qmail support
```

Some finger commands provide also the possibility to query machine information.

For example on a Solaris network where finger is setup:

```
$ finger juser
Login name: juser                    In real life: Joe User
Directory: /home/juser               Shell: /bin/bash
Login             Name          Idle TTY     Host        When   Where
juser Joe User                  0:03 1   machineA     Wed 20:18 >example.org
juser Joe User                  0:20 17  machineB     Wed 20:11 >example.net
No mail.
Plan:
Do this and that ...
```

Or to get a list of free machines:

```
$ finger .free
39 hosts free, 5 not responding.
Free hosts are machineC (idle 2 days, 12:24:49), machineD (idle  3:03:50), 
machineE (idle 1 day,  6:22:53), ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything that does all of that but `rwhod` gets you started.

Run `rwhod` on all nodes. On any one node run `rwho` to see who's logged in on all nodes.