# Determine users of nearby machine from CLI

Tags: networking, ssh, arp

Ok, so at my house I have three computers, and I frequently enjoy using `ssh` and `scp` to run commands that allow me to do wonderful things. Primarily transferring downloaded files, and running media remotely (music, video etc.). Usually I use the `arp -a` command to determine which other computers are on my network, but this only shows the local IP's. I often forget the **users** that exist on my other machines, and I would like to be able to:

**have a command that shows me the users of a remote computer either by network or IP address**

Comment: possibly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20708/how-to-see-who-is-logged-on-to-many-workstations

Answer (score 2):

You can use ssh to execute a command on the remote host, e.g. the `w` or the `who` command.

```
ssh username@otherhost.domain.tld who
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run `rwhod` on each node. Then run `rwho` on any node to list users on other nodes.

`rwho` and `rwhod` are part of the Linux netkit, so most likely it's already packaged with your distribution. Just install it.